# JTextArea drawn wider in Windows 7 at low resolution?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to get some UI components to display in a consistent way, but found a scenario in which they don't : Windows 7 with display resolution set at 1920x1080 vs Windows 7 at 1024x768.

In the low resolution case, I have a JTextArea which is drawn wider than it is at the native screen resolution. I'm trying to figure out why this is the case.

I think Windows 7 displays components with larger margins, but both these cases are in under Windows 7.

I looked into JTextArea.getPreferredSize() and it leads to some calls to getColumnWidth() -> getFontMetrics().getCharWidth(). Does this mean a different font is being used at low resolutions?

Can anyone shed some light on what could be happening?

Comment: `I'm trying to get some UI components to display in a consistent way` - this is the job of the layout manager. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. `Does this mean a different font is being used at low resolutions?` Your SSCCE can include display statement that show the preferred size and Font of the text area when you run at different resolutions.

Comment: Post your code. I think you don't use `LayoutManager` but in this case it is only one way to solve it - use LayoutManager